# Programmatically retrieving IIS log file location in an ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, iis, wmi

I'm trying to determine the location of the IIS log file location of my ASP.NET application. I tried WMI, but wasn't able to find it. Any suggestions?

Note: I want to be able to retrieve the location programmatically; inside my application for further use.
Edit: Here's my code: This works but does not give me the actual physical directory location of the logs. So this is basically useless.

```
ManagementPath p2=new ManagementPath("IIsLogModule.Name='logging/Microsoft IIS Log File Format'");
ManagementObject log = new ManagementObject(scope, p2, objectGet);
log.Get();
logPath.Text = log["__PATH"].ToString();
```

Comment: show your code ?? what you done so far, so that we can help with magic wand :D

Comment: I think that you try to make your life difficult. Where this file are is something that you control, and know, why you won to find them looking some setup files that probably do not have access to them ?

Comment: I edited my question. But I don't believe it will help you, since this code block displays something different than what I need. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: I know where my logfiles are, but this is developed for customers. There is no way I can find where they keep theirs, so I must find the IIS logs of the users of my application programmatically, to process that data.

Comment: @Slethron you are on the right track, but even if you get them, probably you do not have permission to read them, so I think that this is something that you can add to the application setup - or something like because the client need to setup at least the permissions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On IIS7 you could use Microsoft.Web.Administration assembly, [Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.site%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class has a property named [LogFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.sitelogfile_members%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), you can get various info about log file for site, for example log file directory can be obtained with this code:

```
  ServerManager manager = new ServerManager();
  Site mySite = manager.Sites["SiteName"];
  Response.Write("Log file directory : " + mySite.LogFile.Directory + "\\W3svc" + mySite.Id.ToString());
```

I don't like very much that hardcoded part with directory prefix for site, but didn't find any other better way

Answer (score 0):

You should able to use ADSI (or WMI) to do that - browse IIS metabase and look for 'LogFileDirectory' property for the web site node. For example,

```
var root = new DirectoryEntry(@"IIS://localhost/W3SVC");
var sites = root.Children;
foreach(DirectoryEntry site in sites) {
   var name = site.Properties["ServerComment"][0];
   var logFile = site.Properties["LogFileDirectory"][0];
}
```

*Disclaimer:* Untested code

See [this powershell example](http://learn-powershell.net/2011/01/15/locating-iis-logs-with-powershell/) using similar idea.